# Separate template for mobile and desktop in django 2.0

Tags: django

I want to have separate templates for desktop and mobile.
I tried `django_mobile` but it shows the following error

```
mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

my django **version is 2.1**

post your answer considering i am new to django

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [django-user-agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents)  that allows for easy identification of visitor's browser, OS and device information, including whether the visitor uses a mobile phone, tablet or a touch capable device. In your view check for mobile and tablet or pc like this

```
from django_user_agents.utils import get_user_agent

def my_view(request):
   user_agent = get_user_agent(request)
   if user_agent.is_mobile:
       return render(request, my__mobile_template, {'data': data})
   elif user_agent.is_:
       return render(request, my__pc_template, {'data': data})
```

Comment: getting the following error  ```parse_device() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'brand' and 'model' ```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo_view(request):
    data = Model.objects.all()
    my_template = 'template.html'
    """
    your logic for device_info
    """
    if device_info == 'mobile'
        my_template = 'mobile_template.html'
    return render(request, my_template, {'data': data})
```